How does the capacitance of class 2 multilayer ceramic capacitor decrease over time?
There is the figure

Under what conditions does the capacitance decrease with this intensity? Is the voltage zero or maximum DC or AC? Is the temperature minimum or +25°C or maximum?

Not a complete answer so I'll post as a comment:  Prof Sam Ben-Yaakov recently posted a lecture reviewing the (inconclusive) data on MLCC aging https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yLuWcTo2cb4

Class II MLCCs are made from ceramic with a crystalline structure. At high temperature (E.g. after soldering) it's a cubic structure, but when it cools it relaxes to a tetragonal shape at which time it forms dipoles arranged randomly into domain regions. This results in the high permittivity of the dielectric, but unfortunately the dipoles slowly begin to realign within the material causing a gradual loss of permittivity and capacitance over time.
Interestingly, re-soldering or raising the temperature of the capacitor over the Curie temperature re-starts the process and results in the capacitance returning to its original value.
Some manufacturers will quote a "referee" time tr (hrs), and and aging rate A (%/decade hrs).  You can use the referee time to calculate the capacitance aging effect over time (t in hours):
$$ C(t) = C_\text{initial} \left( 1 - \frac{A}{100} \log_{10} \frac{t}{t_r} \right) $$
To my knowledge this happens regardless of voltage bias on the capacitor or AC ripple current in the cap.  I haven't seen any information stating that bias will increase or decrease the effect.
I have to imagine that very cold temperatures would retard the effect, and hot temperatures below the curie temperature might accelerate it, but again I have no data to support that.
The referee time is defined as the number of hours after heating beyond the Curie temperature and cooling that the capacitor is guaranteed to meet the datasheet spec.
Astonishingly, some X5R capacitors (for example) have a 48-hour referee time, meaning that they are only guaranteed to meet the datasheet value for 48 hours after soldering.

On the one, an increase in temperature accelerates reactions. But on the other, shouldn't approaching the Curie temperature slow down the dipoles realigning?

Aging is measured at room temperature and 0V bias, and from the 'last heating'- I believe that is according to the standard(s) as mentioned in your link, but I don't have access to them.
TDK specifies that you should hold the capacitor at 150°C for 1 hour and start the count after cooling for 30 minutes.
Aging presumably is affected by ambient temperature (certainly it is at high ambient temperatures) but I don't see any charts of how it is affected.
The specified tolerance is at the 1000 hour mark so it is acceptable for the capacitor to be out of tolerance (high) initially.
Here is a Wurth document that provides similar information.

The aging is recorded at room temperature (around 20 °C) and ~0 V as
applied voltage. At room temperature and ~0 V ceramic capacitors have
almost no temperature, DC bias and frequency influences that could
influence aging.


This aging happens even at 0 VDC.  It's due to the ferroelectric nature of the dielectric becoming permanently polarized.  High enough temperature (such as reflow soldering) can actually anneal the dielectric and restore the capacitance to the initial value, but it decreases again over time.
Generally the annealing is not practical in real applications, but this is a concern because a marginal design might pass testing immediately after manufacture, but by the time it gets to a customer would no longer meet the specifications.
